# Longest path for knight

Tags: theory, knights, mathematics

Suppose the knight is on square X and he wants to get to square Y, and in order to do that he has to move N moves. how big could N be?

Could that be solved using a mathematical equation? Say Nf3 should capture Bg8, could that be solved mathematically without having to take a look and analyze it step by step? is there an equation?

Comment: Seems to be related to another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339101/knights-shortest-path-chess-question) posted on StackOverflow. Also, a quick googling found a possibly interesting link (http://www.behnel.de/knight.html).

Comment: This question doesn't seem quite complete. Do you mean the largest number of moves without ever occupying the same space? or without making the same exact move (between two spaces) twice? Otherwise Tony's right.

Comment: No without making the same move twice, shortest path. Otherwise the number is obviously infinite and my question is nonsense

Comment: This is most probably solvable with an algorithm. But I don't see the practical application of this for a human player...?

Comment: @RauanSagit I want to see if chess could be solved mathematically, using equations

Comment: @Fischer well, in the case of knight moves, the size of the board is known, the movement rules are known, so writing an algorithm for this should be fully possible. Solving things becomes more tricky in e.g. Texas Hold'Em Poker where you have unknowns. But in chess, most things are known. More tricky would be to solve "how to evaluate this position" or "how to compare this position's evaluation with another position's evaluation". That is already depending on many parameters!

Comment: The question is solved for arbitrary boards: http://books.google.de/books?id=QxX2CX5OVMsC&pg=PA337&lpg=PA337&dq=knight+metric&source=bl&ots=3J5nDWweOY&sig=_-pQwRWZrh0fI9SHzmkxlCb-Xcc&hl=de&sa=X&ei=-FkoU6WaLen8ywOjgoHoDg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The furthest distance is from one corner to the opposite one.  You can get from a1 to h8 in six moves, for example a1,c2,d4,f3,e5,g6,h8.  There are few pairs of squares that take more than four moves.

Answer (score 3):

N can be infinite.  I can always make a zillion knight moves.  So I expect you really want to know the smallest number of moves a Knight needs to get from square A to square B.

Some N's won't work.  A Knight on a1 can't get to b3 in any even number of moves.

One thing we know - if the start and end squares are the same color, it will take an even number of moves.  If they are different colors, it will take an odd number of moves.

It doesn't take long to figure out the longest path on the board (a8 to h1 for example) requires six moves. Note the start and end squares are the same color.  For alternating colors, the requirement is 5 moves, max.

I don't think there will be an equation where one enters the square locations and a single number comes out.

Comment: I think "he _has_ to move N moves. how big could N be?" means that the question is about the smallest number.

Comment: The question is indeed about the smallest number

Answer (score 2):

If the knight cannot touch the same square twice then the answer is 63. See [Knight's tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour)

A coworker of mine wrote the software to determine the route a long time ago.

Comment: may i take a look at the software source code? or is it not open source?

Comment: Sadly, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the options are finites (not infinite) is possible calculate all the possible moves from f3 to g8 so the Knight can take the Bishop but its a longest number.

Since the chess board is finite in dimensions (8x8) all the possible moves can be calculated, but off course it will be again a very longest number.